# List append and wrtite to an output

Tags: python

I am trying to append a string to my list and then write to an file
I used the following code:

```
temp=[line.split() for line in file]
for line in temp:
    line=line.split()
    line.append("string")
    line=" ".join(line[0:-1]))
    outputfile.write(line+'\n')
```

But when I checked the output file, instead of giving me string at the last field, it outputs some random number. Does anyone know what it happened?

Comment: Just a tracing/debugging FYI:  you're reassigning line in your for statement *twice*.

Comment: This shouldn't work at all because each `line` is a list, and lists don't have a `split` method, so everything should error out on the first line of the loop.

Comment: I suggest you to provide a [mcve], since the request seems a little bit confused. Also, to help others (and also yourself!) to better understand the code, use different variable names, each one describing what they represent, and use spacing between operators

Comment: Also, why append `"string"` to the line and then join the line into a string again, without the just added entry?

Comment: I guess I typed split method twice, my fault. The reason I need to split and join is to operate on some of the strings and numbers in between. Not only appending and output. And I have fixed the bug.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you meant, it appends "string" to the end of each line.

```
outputfile = open( 'temp2.txt', 'w' )

temp=[ line.split() for line in open( 'temp1.txt' )]

for line in temp:
    line.append("string")
    line=" ".join(line)
    outputfile.write(line+'\n')
```

Here is another way to do it:

```
outputfile = open( 'temp2.txt', 'w' )

temp=[ line.strip() for line in open( 'temp.txt' )]

for line in temp:
    line = line + " string"
    outputfile.write(line+'\n')
```

Comment: Yes, I fixed it. I think the problem happens when I used line=" ".join(line). It never adds the appended string when I output line.  Once I passed it to a new variable and writes out the new variable, it works.

Comment: @GuBuddy: It never added the appended string, because you explicitly told it to exclude the last element of the list `[0, 1, 2][0:-1]` gives `[0, 1]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
fname = "test.txt"
with open(fname,'r+') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.seek(0)
    f.truncate()
    for line in lines:
        listString = line.split()
        listString.append("your string \n")
        newLine = " ".join(listString)
        f.write(newLine)
```

test.txt

> test
>
> this is a file u read from
>
> and u can add string at the end of each line

output test.txt

> test your string
>
> this is a file u read from your string
>
> and u can add string at the end of each line your string

just make sure to add "\n" at the end of ur line for the new line